# HTML CSS ASP.NET

Tags: html, css

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"
  style="background-image: url('/ProjectSample/images/LoginBox.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Can anyone please let me know whats wrong with this style tag to refer an image which is 
inside folder ->image in my asp.net project - ProjectSample.

```
background-image: url('/ProjectSample/images/LoginBox.png');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly the slash in the background image url? Otherwise it looks ok to me

Comment: Did you set the html base href? and as Sam sayd. I think you should remove the first / of the url

Comment: I think remove slash before projectsample because of it get image from root folder.

Comment: Is there any way to resolve the url ? may be its not picking up the exact image in the folder. The name of my asp.net Project is ProjectSample and i have a folder inside - images.

Comment: By the way, if this is supposed to be the background where the user inputs their login data, why don't you put the background on the table cell where they do that? Or does the image span multiple table cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `ProjectSample` is your ASP.NET project, url should be `images/LoginBox.png`

Comment: No luck with any combination below a) url('SampleProject/images/LoginBox.png') b) url('../SampleProject/images') c) url('SampleProject/images/LoginBox.png') and i tried to match the size of table with images as well. Strange for me. But i really appreciate you guys sharing your time.

Comment: @user1280238: what he is saying is try `url('/images/LoginBox.png')`

Comment: Thanks Francois B and dotNETbeginner...it saved my lot of time. Really appreciate you guys sharing time over my problem. Have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be that you don't give a fixed width and height (according  the image you are using) to your table.
firefox and firebug are your friends - use firebug in order to inspect the table style and try to understand what goes wrong

Comment: Guys its strange if i put url('../ProjectSample/images/LoginBox.png');this image is displayed in design view but the moment i run it in browser its not shown.

Comment: But `../ProjectSample/` is not the same as `/ProjectSample/` as you had in the original question. Why not try what Francois said?

Comment: @user1280238: then try the same adding `runat='server'` to table tag

Comment: what is the url of the page that hold the table?

Comment: make sure that the group users has read permissions for the image file and try it with the ../